# Applying Current Tag Class To Current Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, navigation

I have a NAVIGATION MENU, and within this MENU I have "selected" tags hence "current" tags, referring to the page the user is currently on. So within each HTML page, whatever page the user may be on, within the NAVIGATION MENU, the item in which they selected is HIGHLIGHTED in a sense to inform them on what page they are on.

The problem? I want to be able to automatically do this in JavaScript and or jQuery, because I will be implementing this within a Content Management System, and or an Includes, and wouldn't be able to achieve applying a class to the current page if the NAVIGATION MENU is an Includes oppose to static HTML/CSS.

Does that make sense?
Any ideas?

Thank you so much!
Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven't supplied any code, I can only give you a general example, but this might work, if the URLs are equal to the menu links.

```
$('.navigation>ul>li>a').each(function(){
  if($(this).prop('href') == (window.location.pathname.match(/.*\/(.*)$/)||['',''])[1]){
    $(this).addClass('current');
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried applying this but it did not work, I think it is trying to find the full location of a URL, but all I have is local urls, hence index.html, about.html, etc. This is what I mean... jsfiddle.net/rw9zs So virtually I would have to apply it to .navigation ul li, so I do not interfere with sub-menus. Any ideas? Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you need to apply the class to all li elements or just the top level?

Comment: I edited my answer, but please fill in if I misunderstood. The regex matches only the filename of the path, but it will only work if the files are in the same folder.

Comment: I am sorry to have to say this, but it still isn't working. Yes, they are all in the same folder... But, I tried changing window to document and that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I see that your fiddle includes mootools, and not jquery. Could that be the problem?

Comment: No sir, I am trying to run it locally. With the latest jQuery Version.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5893/discussion-between-aaron-brewer-and-jorgen)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps? Use JavaScript to compare the HREF of each link to the URL of the current page, and highlight it if they match.

```
$('.menulink').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var tarr = location.href.split('/');
    var curr = tarr[tarr.length-1];
    if (href===curr) {
        $(this).addClass('current');
    };
});
```

Comment: I tried applying this but it did not work, I think it is trying to find the full location of a URL, but all I have is local urls, hence index.html, about.html, etc.

This is what I mean...

http://jsfiddle.net/rw9zs/

So virtually I would have to apply it to .navigation ul li, so I do not interfere with sub-menus. Any ideas?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `var path = window.location.pathname;` to grab the url and then from there you could check for the page and match to the nav menu for highlighting elements.